# Getting id from url column in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql table like this:

```
url
---------------
example.com/test.php?id=5
example.com/test.php?id=6&serial=10
example.com/test.php?subsid=7
example.com/test.php?id=7&serial=10&subsid=4
example.com/test.php?subsid=9&serial=10&id=8
```

I want to extract id from the url column. So far I have done the following:

```
select url,substring_index(substring_index(url, 'id=', -1),'&', 1) from thetable
```

But the problem is it gets 7 for the third row too which I dont want. I want to get id only not subsid etc.

One more thing, I want to do it without any PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you saving whole url in table?

Comment: yes, its  a temporary page visit log table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried this on what should be a representative data set.

```
SELECT
  `url`,
  (CASE
    WHEN `url` LIKE '%&id%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`url`, '&id=', -1),'&', 1)
    WHEN `url` LIKE '%?id%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`url`, '?id=', -1),'&', 1)
    ELSE
    0
    END
  ) as `id`
FROM `thetable`;
```

It probably isn't the most efficient way of doing this but it's effective.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9211/5)

Comment: I added the Fiddle (cough, cough).  His trick is to filter each record using `LIKE` _before_ attempting to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`.  And it works great.

Comment: Thanks for adding the Fiddle. This problem is a perfect example of why a regular expression replace function needs to exists. Instead of writing all that, it could be simply `REGEXP_REPLACE(url, '(&|?)id=([0-9]+)', '$2')` and have better validation.

Comment: @DavidFairbanks what does '$2' means?

Comment: If the function existed, it would mean take the value from the second `()`. But unfortunately the function does not exist in mysql yet.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution.  Your biggest problem, from what I can tell, is that you may potentially have both `id=` *and* `subsid=` as query parameters in each url.  This is throwing off your query, because you are capturing the wrong id.

This solution compares the right most substring using `id=` against the *same* substring using `subsid=`.  If they *match*, then it means that we are looking an `subsid=`, and the query moves to the left and checks again.  I do this three times (your sample URLs only have a max of 3 query parameters), but you can add another nested `CASE` if you expect more than 3 parameters.

```
SELECT url,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'id=', -1),'&', 1) =
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'subsid=', -1),'&', 1)
    THEN
        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'id=', -2),'&', 1) =
                  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'subsid=', -2),'&', 1)
        THEN
            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'id=', -3),'&', 1) =
                      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'subsid=', -3),'&', 1)
            THEN NULL
            ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'id=', -3),'&', 1)
            END
        ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'id=', -2),'&', 1)
        END
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'id=', -1),'&', 1)
    END
FROM thetable
```

Try clicking the link below for a live demo.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9211/4)